# Differences between Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing and Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost packages

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing

I have used several times the package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost) to host Asp.Net Core Web API applications in my integration test.

With Asp.Net Core 2.1 the package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing) was released. But Mvc.Testing has a dependency to TestHost.

I was wondering which features Mvc.Testing package is offering on top of the TestHost package. Specially when it is used in functional testing to host an API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` package consists of a set of types (including `TestServer`) to enable hosting your application in-memory for testing purposes. The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` package provides infrastructure to enable functional testing of applications (including the `TestServer`) using the `WebApplicationFactory` class.

Check out the docs for more info about integration/functional testing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests